# Navigating from a TabBarView Child to another Route (full screen)

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout, tabbar, flutter-navigation

I have a TabBarView containg 4 tabs. They all have a button that can be used to navigate to another Route, but the navigation is done in the tabs itself i.e. The tabbed Appbar still exists, how to navigate to those routes without the tabbed appbar.

Edit:
At the home page there are some buttons which take the user to the Tabbed Page,
At that Page the TabBarView has Page 2 with different Strings passed, now Page 2 is used to call a widget which verifies user login, logout and stuff and returns the correct widget. When the user is logged in there's a Fab which takes them to a new route, now that route is still navigating in the tabbed view which i want to change.

TabbedView

```
 home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 4,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: ("Numbers")),
            Tab(text: ("Relationship")),
            Tab(text: ("Word")),
            Tab(text: ("Sentence"))
          ],
        ),
       ------
       ------

      ),
    ),
  ),

      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Page2("Number" ),
          Page2("Relationship"),
          Page2("Word"),
          Page2("Sentence"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Page2

```
return new MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
      home: new Scaffold(
       body: new RootPage(auth: new Auth()
    )
  )
);
```

OnloggedIn

```
return new HomePage(
        userId: _userId,
        auth: widget.auth,
        onSignedOut: _onSignedOut,
      );
```

Fab

```
return new Scaffold(
-----
-----
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //_showDialog(context);
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Levels(
          auth: widget.auth,
          userId: widget.userId,
          onSignedOut: widget.onSignedOut,
        )),);
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the Page2 call in TabBarView and directly calling rootpage .

Comment: can you share how you solved it ?? how you directly call rootpage?? @Akshit Sharma

Comment: In tabbed view instead of calling Page2, I called rootpage directly. @urvashi.                                            body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Rootpage("Number" )
        ],

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap these destination page or route with Scaffold 
code snippet

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(           
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppBarBottomSample());
}

class AppBarBottomSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppBarBottomSampleState createState() => _AppBarBottomSampleState();
}

class _AppBarBottomSampleState extends State<AppBarBottomSample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 6,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('AppBar Bottom Widget'),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bus)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_railway)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_walk)),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
              isScrollable: true,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'CAR', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'BICYCLE', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'BOAT', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'BUS', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'TRAIN', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'WALK', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Click Button '),
              onPressed: () {
                print('hi');
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(title: "hi",)),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working, I checked and made sure that the destination are wrapped in scaffold

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem and here's how I solved it.

- Let's say, on the **HomePage** we have the **TabBarView**,
- And in the **TabBarView**, we have `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3`, which opens `Page1`,
  `Page2` and `Page3`.
- And there is a **TextButton** on `Page1`, which opens `Page4`, after we click
  on it.

The `BuildContext` of **HomePage** `build method` is not same to the `BuildContext` of `Page1`, `Page2` and `Page3` `build method`.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) { //<--I'm talking about this context      
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(           
    title: Text(widget.title),
    bottom: TabBar(
    tabs: [Tab1, Tab2, Tab3],),),
    body: TabBarView(
                    children: [ Page1, Page2, Page3,]
                ),


class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) { //<--This is the context that got passed to Navigator.push(context...........   
                                        //Instead we need the context from HomePage, or from framework.dart, to open the new page in fullscreen   
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(           
    title: Text(widget.title),),
    body: Center(
                    child: TextButton(child: Text('Go to Page4'), 
                                      onPressed: () {
     //Here, the context is passed from Page1 build 
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (newContext) => Page4()));
}
       )
                ),
```

So while calling

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (newContext) => Page4()));
```

if the `context` passed is from the `Page1` build method, then the new page i.e, `Page4` will open only over the `Page1`, and thus the **TabBar** at the top will still be visible.

But if the `context` passed here is from the **HomePage** `build method`, or from the `framework.dart`, then the new Page i.e, `Page4` will open in fullscreen.

So to solve this we either need to

- pass the `context` from **HomePage** to `Navigator.push...`.or
- pass the `context` from `framework.dark`, by renaming the `BuildContext` of **Page1** to something else.

Like This: ---

```
class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext Page1Context) { //<--We are just renaming it to something else.  
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(           
    title: Text(widget.title),),
    body: Center(
                    child: TextButton(child: Text('Go to Page4'), 
                                      onPressed: () {
     //Now, the context passed here is NOT from Page1   
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (newContext) => Page4()));
}
       )
                ),
```

In Android Studio, You can press control and click on `context` in `Navigator.push(context....`, Then it should open the `framework.dart` file. It means the `context` is from `framework.dart` file.